# Oracle seems to ignore all the hints I give it (using sqldeveloper)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, hint

I just wrote out my entire questions and for some reason all the content just randomly deleted, so here we go with a super summed up version.

I am very new to hints and have been taught very little about it, I have done a lot of reading online and watching of Youtube videos but I do not find one that has sufficient examples and visualization that helps me so I apologies if I am just doing it wrong.

So these are the hints I have tried (I tried `USE_NL`, `USE_NL_WITH_INDEX` and `LEADING` but then noticed the CBO automatically used those hints which was good):

```
    /*+ USE_MERGE(sale_saracl CUSTOMER_saracl) */
```

With this query:

```
    SELECT AVG(s.sellprice), s.qty, s.custid  
    FROM CUSTOMER_saracl c, sale_saracl s
    WHERE c.custid = s.custid 
    GROUP BY (s.qty,  s.custid) 
    HAVING AVG(s.sellprice) > (
      SELECT MIN(AVG(price)) 
      FROM  product_saracl 
      WHERE pname LIKE 'FA%'
      GROUP BY price
    );
```

And these are the tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_SARACL( 
    
        CustID         NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
        FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(15),
        SURNAME     VARCHAR2(15),
        ADDRESS     VARCHAR2(20),
        PHONE_NUMBER NUMBER(12)) 
    
        CLUSTER CUST_SALESARACL(CustID); 
    
    CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_SARAHCL( 
    
        ProdID     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
        PName    Varchar2(6),
        PDesc    Varchar2(15),
        Price    Number(8),
        QOH        Number(5))
    
    CREATE TABLE SALE_SARACL( 
    
        SaleID     NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
        SaleDate    DATE,
        Qty            Number(5),
        SellPrice    Number(10),
        CustID        NUMBER(8),
        ProdID        NUMBER(10)) 
    
        CLUSTER CUST_SALESARACL(CustID);
```

The index I am using:

```
    CREATE INDEX customer_index ON CUSTOMER_saracl(custid);
```

When looking at the execution's plan, it does not change one bit when adding any of the hints and that is the issue I am having.

The plan for the query using the `USE_MERGE` hint:

[image: Plan]

Here is the pastebin of the autotrace results on the query with the use merge hint: https://pastebin.pl/view/b72a9a9d

Thank you everyone!

Comment: What is your problem with this query? Do you have any performance issues and why do you think your hinted plan will be better than the optimizer have chosen? Try to collect statistics on your table. According to your model there's no need to use NL in any case because you don't filter customer or sales, hashjoin is sufficient.

Comment: For the assignment, we have to use a hint that is not being used to show that the hint changes the execution plan.

Comment: It would be good to provide your queries with hints, because there may be a lot of things why oracle ignores them. Hint is not a "forcing" method, but instruction. Also, a tracing on optimization steps can be helpful to see why oracle chooses one or another operator.

Comment: That is a good point, I shall most definitely follow that in the future for majority of my queries. Thank you! I am running a autotrace now and I shall post results in this comment via image link.

Comment: Here is the pastebin of the autotrace results on the query with the use merge hint: https://pastebin.pl/view/b72a9a9d

Comment: I mean 10053 trace. Now I don't remember all the stuff about it, but it shows how oracle performs costings of different operators and chooses the lowest-cost plan. You can google and find a lot of information about it. Very good blog on oracle internals is https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/

Comment: Hints are something we don't use generally. We should rely on the optimizer to find the best execution plan. Only when the optimizer is buggy and chooses a horrible plan, should we use a hint for the time being (until the optimzer is fixed). If you just want to prove that hints can change the execution plan, use a simple query like `select * from mytable where id = 123` where the DBMS uses an index and then  use the `NO_INDEX` hint: `select /*+no_index(mytable)*/ * from mytable where id = 123`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for that idea. I do have a index on one of the tables so I will use the NO_INDEX hint to prove that it makes a change in the execution plan. However, she wants me to explain why the MERGE hint is not being followed for me to pass this assignment.

Comment: Even after using /*+ NO_INDEX(CUSTOMER_saracl CUSTOMER_INDEX) */ it still completely ignored my hint and uses the CUSTOMER_INDEX index.

Comment: Same story with /*+ NO_USE_NL(sale_saracl CUSTOMER_saracl) */

Answer (score -1):

The "join" is unnecessary unless `custid` is used for filtering (which I doubt).  You might get a better execution plan with:

```
SELECT AVG(s.sellprice), s.qty, s.custid  
FROM sale_saracl s
GROUP BY (s.qty,  s.custid) 
HAVING AVG(s.sellprice) > (SELECT MIN(AVG(ps.price)) 
                           FROM product_saracl ps
                           WHERE ps.pname LIKE 'FA%'
                           GROUP BY price
                          );
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it is much appreciated! Do you have any idea why the optimizer wont use my hints though? I need to be able to explain it for this paper.